# run different query inside the same modal opened by different <a> tags

Tags: php, html

I have multiple queries.

```
 $tekmuhadiTab=odbc_exec($conn,$tekmuhadi);
 $tekmuhadiTab2=odbc_exec($conn,$tekmuhadi2);

<a href="#" value="altmuhadi"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  style="margin-left: 0.2rem;" class="modalaltfiltre fas fa-search text-sm opacity-10" aria-hidden="true"></a>

<a href="#" value="altmuhadi2"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"   style="margin-left: 0.2rem;" class="modalaltfiltre fas fa-search text-sm opacity-10" aria-hidden="true"></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="baslikana" ></h5>
        <button type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table align-items-center mb-0">   
     <thead>
        <tr>
       <div id="baslik"></div>
       </tr>
       </thead>
    <tbody>
    
      <?php 
    while(odbc_fetch_row($tekmuhadiTab))
    { 

              echo "<td>".odbc_result($tekmuhadiTab,1)."</td>"; //example
              echo "</tr>";         
    }
         ?>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I populate the same myModal with different queries according to corresponding links? I can only write a single query with multiple selects and change the number inside
odbc_result($tekmuhadiTab,1) if it is easier.But I need a condition as it can be seen.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're doing here. There are no `<a>` tags. You probably want to use AJAX with the links though to retrieve the data for each one.

Comment: You want to run a different query each time the modal is opened, you mean? In that case, you'll need to use an AJAX request, so that you can run a request (asynchronously) when the modal is opened in the browser (Javascript can detect this event, and trigger the ajax request to the server). You can then use the data returned from the AJAX request to populate the modal.

Comment: sorry I forgot to change some of the parts @user3783243 , it is edited now

Comment: @ADyson thanks now I see the way but not sure about how to do that, especially about how to return a name of the query from ajax request.

Comment: `how to return a name of the query`...not sure what you mean. You don't need to return the name of a query, you need to return the results of executing the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real way to do what you're asking since you're rendering the result server-side instead of doing queries for it. One possible solution is to create two otherwise identical modals with different IDs and different data.